# Installing nexus error: The version of the JVM must be at least 1.8 and at most 1.8

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have installed `Nexus` on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. When I want to start `Nexus` service I get this error:

```
nexus[24049]: No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
nexus[24049]: The version of the JVM must be at least 1.8 and at most 1.8.
nexus[24049]: Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.
systemd[1]: nexus.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=83
systemd[1]: nexus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: nexus.
```

I have `Open JDK version 10.0.2` installed in my system:

```
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

My question is why `Nexus` uses **ONLY** JDK8? and am I able to have both JDK versions alongside?

Comment: You can have as many JDKs as you want on the same machine. You just have to set the correct JAVA_HOME (INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME for nexus) in your environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME is not an environment variable setting.  It is configured in the nexus installation directory.  You'll need to edit "/bin/nexus" file.

You'll find near the top of that configuration script a commented out line:

```
#  INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=
```

remove the comment tag and set the value to your jdk location.  I set mine to a java 1.8 jdk that I installed.  (Not the JDK 11.0.4 default dir that some linux installations are prepackaged with.  I read somewhere that you must use the Java 1.8 with nexus version 3.x and that other versions will fail.  I don't know the truth to that claim, you certainly can try other version to see if they work.)

After doing that, the nexus service was able to start.

I still haven't been able to get access to the nexus manager through a browser via port 8082.  I'm just now trying to track that issue down. Probably a configuration issue or something else I need to set up.

Comment: by the way, I'm installing nexus 3.18.0-01 on linux mint 19.2

Comment: Oh, the default installation port is 8081, not 8082! So that solved my remaining issue.

Comment: `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` fixed the issue for me. Had `Java 11` installed in my system along with `Java 8` but higher version does NOT work with `Nexus`.